# How to mask zero-padding values in Tensorflow Encoder-Decoder RNN with Attention?

Tags: tensorflow

In the official Tensorflow Neural Machine Translation example (https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention), in the Encoder model, a GRU layer is defined.

However, the zero-padded values will be processed normally by the GRU as there is no masking applied. And in the Decoder I think that the situation is even worse, because the Attention over the padded values will play an important role in the final computation of the context vector. I think that in the definition of the loss function below, the zeroes are masked, but at this point it is too late and the outputs of both the encoder and the attention decoder will be "broken".

Am I missing something in the whole process? Shouldn't the normal way of implementing this be with masking the padded values?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can see that when you print the tensor returned from the encoder that the numbers on the right side of the differ although most of it comes from the padding:
[image]

Usual implementation indeed includes masking. You would then use the mask in computing the attention weights in the next cell. The simplest way is adding something like to `(1 - mask) * 1e9` to the attention logits in the `score` tensor. The tutorial is a very basic one. For instance, the text prepreprocessing is very simple (remove all non-ASCII characters), or the tokenization differs from what is usual in machine translation.

Comment: I agree that when you compute the attention weights you can simply multiply with a large negative number, so that the softmax will be zero. But in the RNN it is also a matter of computational time, you don't want to process all the zeroes. Is there any function or wrapper of RNN in the new Tensorflow that enables something like PyTorch's pack_padded_sequence?

Comment: TensorFlow 1.x used to have `dynamic_rnn` function that worked with different length, but it is not part of the API anymore. In practice, bucketed batching is used for MT, so all sentences in a batch have approximately the same length, so less memory if wasted for padding. This can be done with [`bucket_by_sequence_length`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/bucket_by_sequence_length?hl=en) function.

Comment: Ah ok, I hadn't seen this function, it seems to be a nice one. So this one, in combination with custom masking for the attention scores should do the work. It is just a few more lines of code. Nevertheless, I would like to see somewhere a comparative chart in execution times (TF vs PyTorch) for this task!